# Django, Update Profile, exclude current user email

Tags: python, django, forms, emailfield

I have created an **Update Profile** page. So the fields are: Email, First Name, Last Name.

In the validation, I'm trying to exclude logged user's email address, and also I'm filtering other user's email addresses. I think if you see the code you will understand what I'm talking about.

I read several questions here but couldn't find something. Some users had the same issue.

So with the code below, the issue I'm getting is:
**type object 'User' has no attribute 'email'**.

I tried many ways to get the current user's email address(before I save the form) but still nothing.

forms.py

```
class UpdateProfile(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        current_user_email = User.email
        if User.objects.filter(email__iexact=email).exclude(email__iexact=current_user_email).count() > 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError('This email address is already in use.'
                                        'Please supply a different email address.')
        return email

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UpdateProfile, self).save(commit=False)

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

Comment: are you using the django contrib user model ? Also, which line throws the error ?

Comment: Yes I'm using the django user model. The issue is with getting the current logged in user email address. So it's this line: `current_user_email = User.email`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that in line  `current_user_email = User.email`  "User" isn't really a actual user instance, it is a model class which you imported for setting `model = User` in Meta.
If you want to use this form only for editing user data You should do something like this:

urls.py
    urlpatterns = patterns('project.apps.app_name.views',

```
    url(r'^edit-user/(?P<pk>\d+)/?$','edit_user',name='edit_user'),
)
```

app_name/views.py:

```
def edit_user(request,pk):
    user_instance =  User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    form = UpdateProfile(request.POST, instance=user_instance)
    .... more code ....
```

And in forms.py you should change line from:

```
current_user_email = User.email
```

to:

```
current_user_email = self.instance.email
```

But the proper way to do that (if you use django >1.6)  would be to create custom User model, and set email field attribute `unique=True`.